# Принцип работы GET

Tags: php, get

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, принцип того, как работают `Get` запросы в `php`. После гугла, до меня если честно так и не дошло. Только запутало. Ну, к примеру, есть две кнопки на одной странице. Я хочу чтобы при `GET` запросе, допустим, http://mysite.ru/page.php?id=1 он написал мол ты отправил гет с идом 1, нажав на первую кнопку. А при второй, аналогичное, только мол ид 2 и гет2. Ну как-бы, как-то так..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К примеру есть такая ссылка: `http://mysite.ru/page.php?id=1&name=andrey`

Сам по себе $_GET - это массив параметров, берущийся из строки, в нашем случае это будет:

```
$_GET равен ( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'andrey' )
```

Т.е. мы можем получить параметры так:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

Но,при этом, в адресе могут не оказаться данные, и чтобы он не давал предупреждения или ошибки, можно делать так (я так делаю)

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : -1;  // здесь я ожидаю от int число
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
```

Как пользователю отправить такой запрос. Пишем:

```
<a href='page.php?id=1&name=andrey'>Щелкни</a>
```

Еще один вариант, уже через формы:

```
<form action='page' method='GET'>
   <input type='hidden' name='id' value='1'>
   <input type='text' name='name' value='andrey'>
   <input type='submit' value='отправить'>
</form>
```

Comment: Кажется понятно.. Щас попробую понять это на практике. Если появятся вопросы - я напишу.)

Answer (score 3):

```
http://mysite.ru/page.php?id=1

echo $_GET['id'];//1

http://mysite.ru/page.php?id=1&name=andrey

echo $_GET['id'];//1

echo $_GET['name'];//andrey

echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];//id=1&name=andrey
```

Comment: Ну, рабочий пример у меня есть. Но я не совсем понимаю принцип того, как это работает. И причем тут echo.

Comment: echo выводит то, что содержится в суперглобальном массиве, под нужным индексом.

можешь вот так сделать :

$id = $_GET['id'];//1

теперь поле id будет в переменной id

Comment: А. А допустим как такой запрос отправить кнопкой/ссылкой? Ведь пользователь не должен вводить его сам в адресную строку.

Comment: Просто написать его в ссылке, это обычная строка.